# Using tesseract plugin in ionic 3 project to get text from image

Tags: tesseract

I am getting wrong output, code run perfectly but don't know where is the problem [image]

Comment: When i am trying to get text from this image it gives WEI" in output what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you are faced with is not related to only one point.

There could be problem with cropping: the characters appearing near to the borders may affect on the result.

There is a black line above the text which can also make troubles.

Also the blinking part of the text could become a trouble after preprocessing.

[Here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality) is a helpful link I would recommend to read for improving the OCR quality.

For example if your cases are always a single line text, then you can use `-psm 7` to help Tesseract.